# form redirect to 404 error page using node.js

Tags: node.js, post, contact-form, nodemailer

I'm having some problems trying to send an email from my contact form. I'm using the module NodeMailer.

I'm using node.js and I don't really understand how it works... but anyway, I have this form:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/" class="contact-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="scrollPosition">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 1s" data-sr-init="true" data-sr-complete="true">
        <input required="required" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control input-box" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 1s" data-sr-init="true" data-sr-complete="true">
        <input required="required" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control input-box" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 1s" data-sr-init="true" data-sr-complete="true">
        <input required="required" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control input-box" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" data-scrollreveal="enter right after 0s over 1s" data-sr-init="true" data-sr-complete="true">
        <textarea name="message" rows="12" class="form-control textarea-box" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary custom-button red-btn" type="submit" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 1s" data-sr-init="true" data-sr-complete="true">Send Message</button>                       
</form>
```

and here's my code in index.js :

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var mailOpts, smtpTrans;

//Setup Nodemailer transport, I chose gmail. Create an application-specific password to avoid problems.
  smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
      service: 'Gmail',
      auth: {
          user: "me@gmail.ca",

          pass: "application-specific-password" 
      }
  });
  //Mail options
  mailOpts = {
      from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;', //grab form data from the request body object
      to: 'me@gmail.ca',
      subject: req.body.subject,
      text: req.body.message
  };
  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
      //Email not sent
      if (error) {
          console.log("Failed");
      }
      //Yay!! Email sent
      else {
          console.log("Succes");
      }
  });
});
```

But when I try and press the button "Send Message", it just open the page Not Found 404. I don't understand why. I never used node.js before, I'm using it because the guy I'm working with wanted to use it... So I really have no clue.

There's also "app.js", shall I write this code there instead? I'm kinda lost, we're trying to merge 3 wordpress themes in one and we need to convert everything (because wordpress is php...) and I've been trying to implement the contact form for 2 weeks... and it seems like nothing wants to work.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks a lot.

Here I added the app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
//var knob = require('jQuery-Knob');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var prices = require('./routes/prices');
var projects_startup = require('./routes/projects_startup');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//app.use(knob);

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/prices', prices);
app.use('/projects_startup', projects_startup);



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see your app.js file, everything looks good there, the problem could be when you are posting your form, the browser is expecting a POST page at '/', so you should render a success page, or you can just redirect to the original GET page. You should be able to add a line to your success page.

```
smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
  //Email not sent
  if (error) {
      console.log("Failed");
  }
  //Yay!! Email sent
  else {
      console.log("Succes");
      res.render('successPage')
     //or you can do res.redirect('/')
  }
```

});

Comment: OK, updated my answer now that I've seen the app.js file